# swift3 Table Views in Container Views laggy and not displaying properly

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift3, lag, uicontainerview

I have an iPad UI set up that different views are loaded into a container view on a button press.
Most of these views have 1 or 2 table views in them
When I try to press on the cells in the table views it is very slow and sometimes I have to press for 6/7 seconds before it will call the `didSelectRowAt` function.
One of these tables also has a custom cell, with 2 buttons.  Only the very right portion of one of these buttons is visible, the rest of the button is hidden, however still calling the `touchUpInside` events.

Does anyone know how to fix these issues?